# Different DOTS Tasklets using the same domino objects => "Object has been removed or recycled"

Tags: lotus-domino

I am using one DOTS profile with four DOTS Tasklets. All tasklets are started by a domino directory program document "tell profileName run XYZ" because scheduled tasklets do not work with IBM SBT.

All the tasklets use the same configuration views and documents. Running the tasks at the same time (for example every 60 min), I often get the error "NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled".

How can this be prevented?

It affects different lines of code and only when both Tasklets run simultaneously (same time in the program document, e.g. 60 min).

There are no problems when each DOTS tasklet runs on an individual DOTS profile.

Example 1:

```
NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.CheckObject(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.getSize(Unknown Source)
    at de.gish.gisdots.utils.DominoUtils.isValidDocument(DominoUtils.java:54)


public static boolean isValidDocument( Document doc ) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    try {
        if ( null == doc )
            return false;
        if ( doc.getSize() <= 0 ) //line 54
            return false;
        if( doc.isValid() == false )
            return false;
        if( !doc.hasItem( "Form" ))
            return false;
        if ( doc.hasItem( "$Conflict" ) )
            return false;
        isValid = true;
    } catch ( NotesException ne ) {
        isValid = false;
        LOG.error( ne.getMessage(), ne );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        isValid = false;
        LOG.error( e.getMessage(), e );
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Example 2:

```
NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.CheckObject(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.local.View.getNextDocument(Unknown Source)
    at de.gish.gisdots.adap.db.config.ConfigurationDBInformation.readConnections(ConfigurationDBInformation.java:182)


    public Map<String, ConnectionsConfiguration> readConnections( Database configDB ) throws Exception {
        View viewConnections = null;
        Document docTmp = null;
        Document docConnections = null;
        Map<String, ConnectionsConfiguration> connections = new HashMap<String, ConnectionsConfiguration>();
        try {
            LOG.trace( ">>> Start reading configuration database Connections information" );
            // Ansicht der Connections Dokumente ermitteln
            viewConnections = DominoUtils.getView( configDB, Constants.CONFIGDB_VIEW_CONNECTIONS );
            viewConnections.setAutoUpdate( false );
            // Alle Connections Dokumente durchlaufen
            docConnections = viewConnections.getFirstDocument();
            while ( docConnections != null ) {
                docTmp = viewConnections.getNextDocument( docConnections );  //line 182
                ConnectionsConfigurationReader reader = new ConnectionsConfigurationReader();
                ConnectionsConfiguration connectionsConfig = reader.readFromDominoDocument( docConnections );
                if ( connectionsConfig != null && connectionsConfig.isValid() ) {
                    connections.put( connectionsConfig.getID(), connectionsConfig );
                    LOG.debug( "Connections configuration read: {}", connectionsConfig.toString() );
                }
                DominoUtils.recycleSilent( docConnections );
                docConnections = docTmp;
            }
            return connections;
        } finally {
            DominoUtils.recycleSilent( docTmp );
            DominoUtils.recycleSilent( docConnections );
            DominoUtils.recycleSilent( viewConnections );
            LOG.trace( "<<< End reading configuration database Connections information" );
        }
    }
```

Example 3:

```
NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
    at lotus.domino.local.NotesBase.CheckObject(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.local.Document.getItemValueString(Unknown Source)
    at de.gish.gisdots.adap.db.config.DatabaseAssignmentReader.readFromDominoDocument(DatabaseAssignmentReader.java:20)

    public DatabaseAssignment readFromDominoDocument( Document docDBAssignment) throws Exception{
        if ( DominoUtils.isValidDocument( docDBAssignment ) ) {
            DatabaseAssignment dbAssignment = new DatabaseAssignment( );
            dbAssignment.setId( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "id" ) );
            dbAssignment.setTitle( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "titel" ) );
            dbAssignment.setServer( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "hauptServer" ) );
            dbAssignment.setReplicaID( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "replikID" ) );
            dbAssignment.setCode( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "verwendetesKuerzel" ) ); //line 20
            dbAssignment.setType( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "art" ) );
            dbAssignment.setEnvironment( docDBAssignment.getItemValueString( "f_Mandant" ) );
            return dbAssignment;
        } else {
            LOG.warn( "Invalid database assignment document skiped");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Use try... catch and printStackTrace to get information about what line if code throws the error.  Show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with DOTS tasklets, but I believe the following applies to them just as it would apply to something like a multi-threaded agent. That's because my understanding is that DOTS tasklets all run within the same JVM, and therefore they share one loaded instance of LSXBE.  (LSXBE is the C API logic that operates behind the scenes of the Java classes for Domino.

Within the same JVM, LSXBE arranges things so that all references to the same document share a single back-end representation of the NotesDocument object. The same applies to views, etc. The LSXBE code is tracking all object instances that refer to the same physical NSF structures and routing them through common C API structures.  So, if two threads are operating on the same document, and you recycle the Document object in one thread, then you've recycled it out from under the second thread and you're going to get this error.  To prevent situations like this, you have to make sure that one and only one thread owns the document and recycles it.

In general, you need a broker or a locking mechanism of some kind to prevent two tasklets from using and recycling Java objects that refer to the same underlying physical object.  Typically, in multithreaded agents one might do this by using a dispatcher thread that assigns one database to each worker thread.  This assures no overlap.  It's not as clean if you do it by assigning folders or views to each thread, because the same document can be referenced from multiple folders or views, but you could use Java's synchronization mechanisms for locking documents.

For your common config views and documents, what you might want to do is create a synchronized wrapper class TaskletConfig (or something similar) that opens the view, reads the docs into member variables, and recycles everything.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133244/how-to-lock-a-method-for-a-whole-class-using-synchronized) for info on how to setup an entire class so all objects created with it synchronize methods.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I also believe that this is the problem and I check the suggestions for the improvement.

Comment: Good answer. To add to it. Sample code has a "static" method, which means all tasklets are sharing the same code (even if not threaded). They probably need to create their own reference/dereference mechanism as well.