# Java 'SyncServer' allowing two users to simultaneously to edit a string variable

Tags: java

I'm having a bit of trouble finding the cause of my problem.

Functionality of the program is as follows... the `Server` allows multiple users to log in (connect to the server) and edit the same string variable named `text` with the starting commands of either `rep:` (for replace the whole string) or `app:` (to append to the string).

When the client connects, they have to enter a command. Whatever the command is, it gets echoed back to them in the same window (running the server and client simultaneously in different CMD windows). So if they enter `hello`, the echo would be `ECHO: hello`.

If the command entered is `rep:tight`, the `text` string variable in the server should change to contain `tight` and should then be returned back/ displayed back in the client cmd window as `tight` - without the ECHO.

If the command after that is `app:rope`, the `text` string variable in the server should change to contain `tightrope` and should be returned back/ displayed back in the client cmd window as `tightrope`.

In addition, the user cannot enter any value under 4 characters and thus SynchClient should display an error message and prompt the user to enter another value.

The issue I'm having is the fact that my echoed values are not changing after every new input. I get the return of the first entered command and that's it and I'm struggling to get my head around it all.

EDIT: Might be best if you ran the program yourself.

Here is what my SynchServer.java file looks like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SynchServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Socket client;
        ClientHandler handler;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");

        do
        {
            //Wait for client.
            client = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
            handler = new ClientHandler(client);
            handler.start();
        }while (true);
    }
}

class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
    private Socket client;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintWriter output;

    private static String text = "";

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
        client = socket;

        input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String head, tail, received;

        received = input.nextLine();
        head = received.substring(0, 4);
        tail = received.substring(4);

        while (!received.equals("QUIT"))
        {
            if (head.equals("rep:"))
                changeText(tail);

            else
                if (head.equals("app:"))
                    appendText(tail);

            output.println(text);
            output.println("ECHO: " + received);
        }

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
            client.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("* Disconnection problem! *");
        }
    }

    private synchronized void changeText(String changedText)
    {
        text = changedText;
    }

    private synchronized void appendText(String appendedText)
    {
        text += appendedText;
    }
}
```

and my SynchClient.java file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SynchClient
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InetAddress host = null;
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Socket socket;
        Scanner networkInput,keyboard;
        PrintWriter output;

        try
        {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHost ID not found!\n");
        }

        socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
        networkInput = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String message, response;

        do
        {   
            System.out.print("\nEnter message ('QUIT' to exit): ");
            message = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (message.length() < 4)
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter a value greater than 4 characters: ");
                message = keyboard.nextLine();
            }

            output.println(message);

            if (!message.equals("QUIT"))
                {
                    response = networkInput.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("\n" + response);
                }
        }while (!message.equals("QUIT"));

        try
        {
            System.out.println("\nClosing down connection...\n");
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\n* Disconnection problem! *\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:
My Working Solution:**

Server:

```
public class SynchServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Socket client;
        ClientHandler handler;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");

        do
        {
            //Wait for client.
            client = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
            handler = new ClientHandler(client);
            handler.start();
        }while (true);
    }
}

class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
    private Socket client;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintWriter output;

    private static String text = "";

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
        client = socket;

        input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String head, tail, received;

        received = input.nextLine();

        // create head and tail in case first input is rep: or app:
        head = received.substring(0, 4);
        tail = received.substring(4);

        while (!received.equals("QUIT"))
        {
            if (head.equals("rep:"))
            {
                changeText(tail);
                output.println(text);
                // input for next one
            }
            else
                if (head.equals("app:"))
                {
                    appendText(tail);
                    output.println(text);
                    // get input for next
                }
            else
            {
                //must be some random thing that just needs to be echoed
                output.println(text);
            }

            //Get next input
            received = input.nextLine();
            //and set the head and tail again
            head = received.substring(0, 4);
            tail = received.substring(4);
        }

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
            client.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("* Disconnection problem! *");
        }
    }

    private synchronized void changeText(String changedText)
    {
        text = changedText;
    }

    private synchronized void appendText(String appendedText)
    {
        text += appendedText;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class SynchClient
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InetAddress host = null;
        final int PORT = 1234;
        Socket socket;
        Scanner networkInput,keyboard;
        PrintWriter output;

        try
        {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHost ID not found!\n");
        }

        socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
        networkInput = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String message, response;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter message ('QUIT' to exit): ");
            message = keyboard.nextLine();

            while (message.length() < 4)
            {
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter 4 or more characters: ");
                message = keyboard.nextLine();
            }

            output.println(message);
            if (!message.equals("QUIT"))
            {
                response = networkInput.nextLine();

                System.out.println("\n" + response);
            }

        }while (!message.equals("QUIT"));

        try
        {
            System.out.println("\nClosing down connection...\n");
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\n* Disconnection problem! *\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a funny case when absolutely broken code receives so many votes-up :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not primarily about `static` fields at all. Your mistake is in this loop:

```
       while (!received.equals("QUIT")) {
            if (head.equals("rep:"))
                changeText(tail);

            else if (head.equals("app:"))
                appendText(tail);

            output.println(text);
            output.println("ECHO: " + received);
        }
```

It runs infinitely after first client input and do not read new value from input stream each time.

These lines:

```
        received = input.nextLine();
        head = received.substring(0, 4);
        tail = received.substring(4);
```

should be put into the loop:

```
    while (!received.equals("QUIT")) {
        received = input.nextLine();
        head = received.substring(0, 4);
        tail = received.substring(4);
        ...
```

**UPDATE**:

To be precise it has another, secondary problem, these two lines:

```
            output.println(text);
            output.println("ECHO: " + received);
```

They should be changed into just:

```
        output.println("ECHO: " + text);
```

(otherwise you send two separate lines which is not desired).

Comment: While this is true, it does not mean that the broken synchronization is not an issue as well.

Comment: This code is so broken, so it is too far from solving synchronization problems :)

Comment: this is the correct answer; my suggestion for static locks should also be applied, for sync issues, but after applying what Andremoniy's suggests. Vote up

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You've helped me realise a few vital issues with my code logic! (Should I update the question with my solution that now works 100% as intended?)

Comment: @Olehi yes please.. I want to see the working solution.

Comment: @AnshulJain Hi. Please see EDIT 2 in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a synchronized block that applies to each object separately, not every object, as synchronized block applies to objects not the whole class.

You may use a static lock, so all clients wait for their turn. Check this link to see the comparison between static and not static locks

[Static versus non-static lock object in synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356795/static-versus-non-static-lock-object-in-synchronized-block)

and this

[How to lock a method for a whole class using synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133244/how-to-lock-a-method-for-a-whole-class-using-synchronized)

---

So, you should eliminate `static` modifier from `text` field declaration:

```
private String text = "";
```

In this case you do not need `synchronized` for `changeText` and `appendText` methods at all.

Comment: Ops, my first edit was deeply incorrect. I'm sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Well, I've read you answer again. You are talking about adding `static` blocks, what is incorrect. In this case it will be also broken code for multiclient case.